# In regards to continues subtraction

Tags: java, swing

I made a swing calculator as part of homework that I did and would like some advice on continues subtraction in particular.
With continues adding up it is straight forward enough(i.o.w. adding the operands and then to continue adding from there onwards). This is what I did.

```
if(totalCount > 1)
    {
        if(sbOne.length() > 0)
        {
            operandOne = Double.parseDouble(sbOne.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            operandOne = 0;
        }

        if(sbTwo.length() > 0)
        {
            operandTwo = Double.parseDouble(sbTwo.toString());

        }
        else
        {
            operandTwo = 0;
        }
        result = operandOne + operandTwo;
        totalResult += result;
        screenResult = Double.toString(totalResult);
        txtDisplay.setText(screenResult);
        notCalculate = true;
        sbOne.setLength(0);
        sbTwo.setLength(0);
```

How can I achieve the same result by subtracting one operand from another and then to continue subtracting from there onwards.

Comment: You mean like `totalResult -= result;`?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking here.. Short of ^

Comment: Sorry, perhaps bit confusing, with the above I will...for example add 34 + 55 + 3454 + ...etc. the totalResult will be displayed every time I click on the '+'. Trying to follow tthe same logic as abouve but only subtracting instead...i.o.w. for example...456 - 66- 321...and the result the being displayed every time I click on '-'

Comment: Add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to get the faster response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems confusing, particularly as it is incomplete and not compilable.  My interpretation of your code is as follows: you have two presumably positive values which you add together, whereupon you add that sum to a total which you already have.  My interpretation of your question is as follows: you want to subtract that sum from the total.  A solution to that is as Hot Licks said, which is just to use the following operation: `totalResult -= result;`.  If you want to make it possible to decide whether or not you want to add or subtract, add a Boolean flag, namely:

```
/*somewhere in your code to determine whether you add or subtract,  
  have a button or something which changes this value.
*/
boolean isAdding = true;

//...

//button pressed
isAdding = false;

//...

//your calculating code goes here
if(isAdding)
    totalResult += result;
else
    totalResult -= result;

//all of the other stuff
```